# WinJS xhr returns 0 when accessing webservices on VPN

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors, winjs

I have tried searching for a relevant answer for this one on all forums , but nothing actually has worked for us as yet. Appreciate if someone can actually help us in this regard as we have an impending release in a few days

We have created a WinJS based windows desktop app which is consuming Oracle SOA based web services (http based) over VPN / or a dedicated APN configuration

whenever we try to access the services we get a Status 0 as return value for xhr ( which is i assume related to response is null )  & get this in the

WinJS.xhr: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd

We tried using various suggested options like allowing Private Network in the manifest file ( assuming this is a CORS issue) , but to no avail

"Private Networks (Home & Server)"

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
</Capabilities>
```

We have been working around using Fiddler (loopback option) but that's just temporary , can someone suggest ,what we might be missing or given their experience tell us what could be wrong with our approach.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: So the first thing to know is that WinJS.xhr is just a lightweight JS wrapper around XMLHttpRequest, so really WinJS isn't likely a factor here at all.

Comment: It looks like you're calling this in a Windows app and not the browser, so CORS likely isn't a factor here. Can you specify which OS version you're building for? And whether this code is running in the local compartment or not (i.e. in regular JS code included in your app package, not in the web compartment via iframe/WebView or anything)? If it isn't throwing an error or returning an error code, where did you get the 2efd error? Also how is Fiddler affecting this? Does it work just by having Fiddler running? That could indicate a proxy server configuration issue on your machine.

Comment: Hi Brandon,
Appreciate your prompt response & here is what I know
1. The Windows app is currently running on 8.1
2. If we use fiddler ( as local proxy,providing loopback exemption) this works fine with our VPN connected server 
3. When not using fiddler we get an error on app saying webservice call failed with status 0 ( on looking at the logs/ console we get WinJS.xhr network error 0x2efd...)
4. We don't have any iframe / webviews , so ideally all js code runs in the container
5. If we connect the tablet using a network cable without fiddler , we don't have any issues at all.

Comment: So it sounds like you definitely have a proxy or VPN configuration issue. This really has nothing to do with CORS or even your code.

On suggestion from MS's support site for issues like this is:
Go into your VPN's properties. Then Networking,  Properties,  Advanced and under IP Settings uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network".

Comment: Hi Brandon, Appreciate this , but probably another silly question , we are connected through the juniper pulse secure client & somehow i haven't found a way to see the VPN properties when connected through this, any suggestions on how to see that?

Comment: That I can't really help with. I don't know anything about that VPN software or your network setup.

One thing you *could* try (but probably won't help) would be to use the WinRT HTTPClient instead of XHR. I wrote a wrapper a couple of years ago to ease migration to this. It has some limitations, but might be an easy way to test if it makes a difference for you:

https://gist.github.com/BrandonLive/8641828

Comment: Sure let me try to get help on the VPN thing first & if doesn't happen , probably go back to the code & evaluate the above suggestion :) , I really appreciate your prompt help on this Brandon , owe you one.

Comment: Good luck! And note that to try that out it should be really straightforward. Just include that file, then change your WinJS.xhr call to BrandonJS.xhr and see if it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

`WinJS.XHR` returns `response.status === 0` when you don't have access to the Internet. Unfortunately this is treated like a success in **WinJS 3.0**:

```
if ((req.status >= 200 && req.status < 300) || req.status === 0) {
   schedule(c, req, priority);
} else {
   schedule(e, req, priority);
}
```

In **WinJS 4.x** they changed the condition, so that it :

```
if ((req.status >= 200 && req.status < 300) || 
(req.status === 0 && options.url.substr(0,7) === 'file://')) {
   schedule(c, req, priority);
} else {
   schedule(e, req, priority);
}
```

and more recently in 4.4:

```
if ((req.status >= 200 && req.status < 300) || (isLocalRequest && req.status === 0)) {
   schedule(c, req, priority);
} else {
   schedule(e, req, priority);
}
```

See: https://github.com/winjs/winjs/commit/8d44a3ee4105aa05fb69cd82943b9c07500bf523

This means that on your success promise callback you will receive an empty response.

```
WinJS.XHR({[...]}).then((response: XMLHttpRequest) => {
   // Here response.status === 0 instead of error in the error handler!!!
}, (error) => console.log(error));
```

**Solution**

1. Use Charles Proxy (maybe Fiddler doesn't show responses right) to see what is happening behind the scenes with your request. Most likely fails.
2. Depending on your version of WinJS use:
   a. success handler and output the response when response.status ==== 0
   b. error handler and same as above.